# How to join two primary partitions windows 10

Tags: partitioning, windows-10

I have a C drive and E drive. Both of them are primary. I have very less space left in my C Drive. How would I join these two partitions. So, that I can extend C Drive with E drive to make them one.

[image]

Comment: Windows does not have the ability to merge partitions without losing data. This is due to the partition tables and other disk maps. Third party software may help but at a cost. It is recommended to backup both your C and E drives -> delete the E drive -> extend the C drive to use the space your E drive used -> copy the E drive files to the extended C drive from your backup.

Comment: You can't.  You can't even do it with third-party software because the drive is encrypted with Bitlocker.  So you would need to delete the partition then extend the system partition.  You might find it easier to get yourself a new drive, duplicate the first two partitions on that drive, with the size you want then duplicate the other two partitions after you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this, is by deleting the E drive partition, then alter the size (expand) the C drive.

This means, that you'll first have to backup all the data on the E drive to a safe location, for example an external harddrive, or another pc in your network if available.

Do note, the E partition is bitlocked, so you are likely going to need to unlock it first.

Once the partition is empty, right-click it and choose delete partition. Then right click on the C partition and choose expand.

Please note, by removing the partition, all data will be removed. If any backup failed, you will not be able to retrieve that data. If you can't risk losing your data and you don't feel confident about proceeding, ask someone to do it for you or live with the small size.

Comment: @androidplusios.design good to hear. Feel free to accept this answer, so other people know you no longer need any help.